# Parallel downloading and get individual download progress via AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, threadpoolexecutor

I am working on parallel downloading of files using

```
asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)
```

I want the individual progress of the every Task I add.

```
ArrayList<AsyncTask> mListAsync = new ArrayList<>();
final DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(mContext, name);
downloadTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,mVideoUrl.trim());
mListAsync.add(downloadTask );
```

Above is the sample code I use to download file and I do maintain an arraylist to get how many tasks has been added in que.

Is there any way that I can get the individual AsyncTask progress update added in Thread Pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your DownloadTask class uses the https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...) method, you can get the current progress in a callback from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)

EDIT:
Some sample code with a callback:

```
public class SampleTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {

    private final int id;
    private final ProgressCallback callback;

    public SampleTask(int uniqueId, ProgressCallback callback){
        this.id = uniqueId;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // do work and call publish progress in here
        for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            publishProgress(i);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        //handle progress updates from in here
        callback.onProgress(id, values[0]);
    }
}

public interface ProgressCallback{
    void onProgress(int uniqueId, int progress);
}
```

Comment: The issue is it can be done for the single async. What if I am using `asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)` How can I get separate progress for each async call.?

Comment: I do not quite follow what you mean. Each AsyncTask that will be submitted to the executor defined by AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR. When they are executed the publishProgress will update the progress for the AsyncTask that is running.

If you are asking how to tell apart the AsyncTasks when they execute, you can have another parameter for DownloadTask when you make it to help differentiate it. This could be as simple as an unique int or even a callback that handles when progress is given.

Comment: Edited my answer with an example

Comment: Got that!! Thanks:)